# clojure get data out of json response

Tags: json, clojure

I have an json response and would like to get the values out:

```
(cheshire.core/parse-string (:body picList))

{"photoset" {"primary" "8455893107", "total" "1", "pages" 1, "perpage" 500, "page" 1,
"per_page" 500, "photo" [{"id" "8455893107", "secret" "1a3236df06", "server" "8087", 
"farm" 9, "title" "IMG_0137", "isprimary" "1"}], "owner" "93029076@N07", "id" 
"72157632724688181", "ownername" "clojureB5"}, "stat" "ok"}
```

How can I get the different values like photoset->primary or photoset->photo->id ?
I tried something with `(map #(get % "photoset")...` but it doest work.

Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think you're looking for [clojure.core/get-in](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/get-in)

```
(get-in your-parsed-json ["photoset" "primary"]) ;; "8455893107"

(-> (get-in your-parsed-json ["photoset" "photo"])
  first
  (get "id")) ;; "8455893107"

(get-in your-parsed-json ["photoset" "photo" 0 "id"]) ;; "8455893107"
```

Comment: yes, thats working! And how can I get the values inside the photo? ["photoset" "photo" "id"]) is not working...

Comment: adding "id" will not work because the key "photo" points to a `vector`. Notice how the second example calls `first` on that vector to get the actual map.

Comment: The second example is similar to `(get-in json ["photoset" "photo" 0 "id"])`

Comment: @hsestupin I didn't think of that. Nice one!